# Connecting to a remote SQL Server database from Heroku containerized app

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker, heroku

I currently have a containerized .net core application using docker, with a connection string that connects to a remote SQL Server database, and I get a "Cannot connect to SQL Server Browser. Ensure SQL Server Browser has been started" error when the application attempts to connect to the remote server instance. As the message entails, what are the possible solutions to install and use an SQL Server browser or client within a containerized app on Heroku?

Comment: The SQL Browser service is typically used with Named Instances of SQL Server. It listens on tcp/1434 and acts like a phone book directory - given the name of a Named Instance it returns the TCP port that named instance is listening on, thus directing clients to the actual tcp/whatever port that instance uses. The SQL Browser service isn't required if you're just using the default-named instance, e.g.: `FooServer\MSSQLSERVER` will be listening on tcp/1433 and clients could just connect to `FooServer` (without using an instance name or the SQL Browser service).

Comment: Thanks for the info, turns out that there was a typo in my connection string. Thanks again!

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Not sure whether I should delete the question or not, would you mind writing that on an answer so I can accept it, because it might be useful for someone.

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Browser service is typically used with Named Instances of SQL Server. It listens on tcp/1434 and acts like a phone book directory - given the name of a Named Instance it returns the TCP port that named instance is listening on, thus directing clients to the actual tcp/whatever port that instance uses. e.g.: `FooServer\HOMESHOPPING` could resolve to an SQL Server instance listening on tcp/50503 of the `FooServer` machine.

The SQL Browser service isn't required if you're just using the default-named instance, e.g.: `FooServer\MSSQLSERVER` will be listening on tcp/1433 and clients could just connect to `FooServer` (without using an instance name or the SQL Browser service).